# Does str_replace() block ( ' ) in a string

Tags: php, str-replace, textblock

I have a code for submitting an article which in this form there is a title input and file input for the article file.

but problem is if in the title i write for `ex : this is hi's article` 
this article would not submit and will fail. the code for replacing spaces in title is :

```
//pereventing spaces for article title
$pdf_file=str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['msfile']['name']);

/* define the path to the upload folder */
$destination='../pdf/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['msfile']['tmp_name'], $destination.$pdf_file); 


//inserting info into articles
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die("cannot connect");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");      

$sql1=mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `{$tbl_name}`  (`uname`,`title`,`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`mstitle`,`msfile`,`date`,`status`) 
VALUES ('{$log_row["uname"]}' , '{$log_row["title"]}' , '{$log_row["fname"]}' , '{$log_row["lname"]}' , '{$log_row["email"]}' , '{$_REQUEST['mstitle']}','{$pdf_file}','{$mydate}','Awaiting Processing' )");
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: I suggest reading on SQL injections. That's exactly why they need to be avoided: not just for Little Bobby Table, but for the innocent apostrophe that can destroy your query

Comment: what @DamienPirsy said. It is the ' breaking your query, look at using prepared statements, or something like `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: thanks for the respond but i know about sql injection but i need to unblock < ' > in the code because my client's would not accept to block it and they want to write everything in title unfortunately

Comment: ...in OP's case, that would be `mysql_real_escape_string()` yet `mysqli_` functions are best, considering the deprecation of `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @anonymox Your comment shows you don't know enough about SQL injections. I repeat, it's not just the malicious user that tries to drop your user table, it's mainly for being able to use an apostrophe.

Comment: You can also look into `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` and/or just doing another replace `'` for `\'` - You have many options available at your disposal. Prepared statements work best.

Comment: so can i change mysql_query to mysql_real_escape_string() and be able to accept < ' > in title ?

Comment: It should, give it a try. Yet, use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Comment: you would need to use mysql_real_escape_string to escape all the string values, and then use those values to build your query

Comment: Thanks for responding, yeah i've been using mysqli in my new codes. but it's an old website and i don't want to try hard on all of the pages it should redesign from the top. i just need to fix this part.